# Date equivalent for "less than or equal"

Tags: word-usage

I'm developing a software, and I have to indicate in a selection menu the equivalent of "less than or equal" for a date field.

Since we already have "Before" value, who doesn't take in account the selected date, what value can we use?

I was thinking about "Before or On", but my colleague doesn't agree.

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't your colleague agree? Personally, I think, as already commented on, that it should be *on or before* but I'm curious to hear if there is an objection on grounds other than word order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ColleenV implies in a comment above, the most common phrase is "on or before [date]". [[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+or+before%2C+before+or+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20or%20before%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbefore%20or%20on%3B%2Cc0)]

Alternatively, if you are expressing a deadline (due date) or similar, it may be better to use "by [date]"; "on or before [date]" is still correct in such contexts, but "by [date]" is much more common. [[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=must+be+submitted+on+or%2Cmust+be+submitted+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmust%20be%20submitted%20on%20or%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmust%20be%20submitted%20by%3B%2Cc0)]